# How to use negative expression in Cucumber Java

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

In Cucumber you can write Then expressions and their step definitions to verify the results. The problem is I don't want to write 2 different step definitions for checking the outcome. One example would be like this:

```
Then the transaction is successful
```

and

```
Then the transaction is not successful
```

How can I get around this?
I've found out that in Ruby you could consolidate step definitions by using capturing optional groups as described [[here]](http://coryschires.com/ten-tips-for-writing-better-cucumber-steps/). That is:

```
Then /^I should( not)? see the following columns: "([^"]*)"$/ do |negate, columns|
  within('table thead tr') do
    columns.split(', ').each do |column|
      negate ? page.should_not(have_content(column)) : page.should(have_content(column))
    end
  end
end
```

But I don't know whether this is possible in Java or not. And even if it is what type of variable should I be capturing?

Comment: U can use the same for Java too, if u want to capture the text into a String variable. Though there will be a leading space when "not" step is run. If u do not want to capture use this regex - "^the transaction is(?: not)? successful$"

Answer (score 3):

Why not write two step definitions. Each one is simpler, on topic, doesn't require a regex. If you delegate the work the step definitions do to a helper method you can remove almost all of the code duplication as well

```
Then I should see the following columns |cols|
  should_see_cols(cols)
end

Then I should not see the following columns |cols|
  should_not_see_cols(cols)
end
```

Now you have super simple crystal clear step definitions and you can write your method/ methods however you want.

Step definition duplication is irrelevant if all your step definitions just make a single call to a helper method. You can be as DRY as you like with your helper methods and still keep your scenarios super simple and remove the need to use regex's and complex logic in your step defs.

Comment: I totally agree, having two separate step definitions makes more cleaner and efficient implementation.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, I would create one method with capture groups (is|is not), and derive a boolean from that which I would compare to the value. On the other hand, this adds logic to your test implementation so there is something to be said for @diabolist's solution of having 2 distinct step definitions.